# Cannot GET api express application

Tags: node.js, express

I got this error "Cannot GET /api/data" 
it s working good on my local host , but when I upload it to server it show me this error,
this is a simple code for testing that also show me the same .

my index page

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const port = 4000;
const route = require('route');

const data = require('./routes/data.js');


const app = express();

app.use(bodyparser.json());
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
// parse the raw data
app.use(bodyparser.raw());
// parse text
app.use(bodyparser.text());


app.use('/data', data);


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("working");
});
```

/routes/data.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const add = require('../classes/insert');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
var con = require('../Modules/connection');
const app = express();


app.use(bodyparser.json());
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
// parse the raw data
app.use(bodyparser.raw());
// parse text
app.use(bodyparser.text());

app.get("/",(req, res)=>{
   res.send("hello");
   });

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.use('/data', data)
```

This will only work on /data route. If you want this work on /api/data, use the following snippet.

```
app.use('/api/data', data)
```

Comment: thanks , I have a folder called "api" under the domain name s root and api is just for the the folder where the app exist .

Answer (score 0):

this error may be comming because of the file path. Try using `__dirname` in spite of `./` and also check your file structure.
Hope this works.

Comment: the error you are getting is from console or from browser?

Comment: it s from browser bro

Comment: can you tell me the URL from which you are getting this error

Comment: sure , getintohome.store/api/data

Comment: change route to /api/data in this app.get("/",(req, res)=>{
   res.send("hello");
   });

Comment: thanks , I have tried this before and I solve it yesterday , there are two things to be changed , first is what you mention adding '/api' before data , second is using router.get instead of app.get , thank you for your help :)